# Telegram Bot -UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 400: Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf, node-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to get chat from one user using my telegram bot. Below is my code so far

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);


bot.telegram.getChat('username', async (ctx) =>{'incoming message ', console.log(ctx.message.tesx)})
```

from Doument

```
(method) Telegram.getChat(chatId: string | number): Promise<ChatFromGetChat>
Get up to date information about the chat (current name of the user for one-on-one conversations, current username of a user, group or channel, etc.).

@param chatId — Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target supergroup or channel (in the format

@channelusername — )
```

so in my parameter i use the username of that particular chat (not group chat, only 1 person) but it return chat not found.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the chat and chat id for the getChat instead of just passing a string.

```
bot.telegram.getChat(ctx.message.chat.id, ctx.message.chat, async (ctx) =>
    {'incoming message ', console.log(ctx.message.tesx)})
```

Answer (score 0):

One Thing to Check here is if the Channel or Group is Private. Make sure the Channel is Public.
and this is how you use the send message function.

```
await bot.telegram.sendMessage('@channel_username', 'message text', Markup.inlineKeyboard([
{text: 'button text',  url: `https://t.me/xxxx_bot?start=${data.id}`}]);)
```